# conditionally change the scale_shape_manual values based on the column values in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to conditionally change the shapes based on the values within a column, is it possible, i tried the below code and it did not work, any thoughts. I tried using the *case_when()* within *scale_shape_manual()*
here the **avalc** variable is available in **adrs3_all** dataset which i am passing in the *geom_point()*

```r
adrs4 <- structure(list(subjid = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"), class = "factor"),  ady = c(38, 84, 111, 111, 242, 242), avalc = structure(c(3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L), levels = c("CR", "PR", "SD", "PD", "On-treatment",  "EOT", "Death"), class = "factor"), trtedy = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 242), trtpn = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), trtp = c("TRT A",  "TRT A", "TRT A", "TRT A", "TRT A", "TRT A")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

adrs3_all <- adrs4 <- structure(list(subjid = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"), class = "factor"),  ady = c(38, 84, 111, 111, 242, 242), avalc = structure(c(3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L), levels = c("CR", "PR", "SD", "PD", "On-treatment",  "EOT", "Death"), class = "factor"), trtedy = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 242), trtpn = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), trtp = c("TRT A",  "TRT A", "TRT A", "TRT A", "TRT A", "TRT A")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot((adrs4 %>% filter(trtpn==1)),aes(reorder(subjid,trtedy), trtedy)) + # Base axis
    geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=factor(trtp))) +
    geom_point(data=(adrs3_all %>% filter(trtpn==1)), # Use df.shapes to add reponse points
               aes(subjid, ady, colour=avalc, shape=avalc), size=10) +
    coord_flip() +
    theme(text=element_text(family="sans")) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c('darkcyan','brown','darkviolet','red','forestgreen','darkgoldenrod2','black')) +
    scale_shape_manual(values=case_when(avalc=='Death' ~ c(rep(unicode[["cross"]], 1), # Add shapes
                                                           avalc=='EOT' ~ rep(unicode[["star"]],1),
                                                           avalc=='PD' ~ unicode[["square"]],
                                                           avalc=='SD' ~ unicode[["circle"]],
                                                           avalc=='On-treatment' ~ rep(unicode[["arrow"]],1),
                                                           avalc=='PR' ~ rep(unicode[["triangle2"]],1),
                                                           avalc=='CR' ~ unicode[["triangl1"]], 1)), guide = "none") +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,600),breaks=seq(0,600,50)) +
    labs(fill="Treatment", colour="Response", shape="Response",  # Add labels
         x="Subject ID ", y="Days",
         title="Swimmers Plot",subtitle = 'All Treated Subjects', size=20) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 1.5), # Put title in the middle of plot
          plot.caption = element_text(size=15, hjust=1.5),
          legend.text = element_text(size=15)) +
    theme_classic(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the data needed to run your code? Try pasting the output from `dput(adrs4)`. If its too big, you can paste the first lines only

Comment: I updated the question with the data, could you please check and help

Answer (score 0):

You’ve made things a bit more complicated than you need to. You can just pass a vector of shapes to `values` in `scale_shape_manual()`. You may have to change the order so the shapes you want “line up” with the values you want.

```
library(ggplot2)

# example `unicode` vector
unicode <- c(star = "*", square = "#", circle = "@")

ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_point(aes(cty, hwy, color = drv, shape = drv), size = 6) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(
    unicode[["star"]], 
    unicode[["square"]], 
    unicode[["circle"]]
  ))
```

[image]

And if, for example, you wanted `"4"` to correspond to the square and `"f"` to the star, you would either change the order of the `values` argument:

```
# ...
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(
    unicode[["square"]],
    unicode[["star"]], 
    unicode[["circle"]]
  ))
```

Or alternatively, change the levels order of `drv`:

```
library(dplyr)

mpg2 <- mpg %>%
  mutate(drv = factor(drv, c(“f”, “4”, “r”))

ggplot(mpg2) +
  # ...
```

Comment: Thank you @zephryl for your response. I am fine with the shape values that i gave through unicode, it does not result in error, the main question i have is about controlling the shape of the values based on the variable value avalc, if the avalc has a value as 'SD' then a particular shape it has to take and so on. this way when i pass a different data also, for that value the shape will be constant else now what is happening is when i change the data the shape is applying to a different value

Comment: @jkatam right, the code in my answer should do that for you — you would just replace `"f"`, `"r"`, etc with the values of `avalc` — `"Death"`, `"EOT"`, etc. You can use your own `unicode` vector, I just created one for this example.

Comment: if i am doing that then i am Gettig two legends one for shape and one for color, also the shape does not get colored in legend its black, and in color legend i see circle filled with different colors and respective labels

Comment: @jkatam right you are. Have a look at my edited answer for a solution.